Cannot able to import the UI Package from Figma to Android Studio using Relay
I am trying to import the UI package from Figma to Android Studio using Relay but it gives me an error in Android Studio when I place the link of my design.
In this image Android Studio gives me an error that Figma design's URL must start https://www.figma.com/file... but my design's URL starts https://www.figma.com/design...

Here is my Figma design. As you see in Figma my design's URL starts with https://www.figma.com/design...

How can I overcome this error?
I want to import my Figma design from Figma to Android Studio using Relay.
